# Convert XLSX to PDF on one page by Spire.Pdf (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, pdf

I have one page XLSX work sheet (invoice). I need to convert it to one page PDF document. For it I am using Spire library. But it covert my document to two pages.

Code:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackageRef = new ExcelPackage(totalXlsFile))
{
    using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(workXlsFile))
    {
        ExcelWorkbook wb = xlPackage.Workbook;
        ExcelWorkbook wbRef = xlPackageRef.Workbook;
        var sheetName = invoice.XlsSeznamFakturNazevListu;
        OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet wsRef = wbRef.Worksheets[sheetName];
        if (wsRef != null)
        {
            // create xls work file
            wb.Worksheets.Add("faktura", wsRef);
            xlPackage.Save();

            // load Excel file
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.LoadFromFile(workXlsFilePath);

            // pdf file path
            FileInfo pdfInvoiceFile = new FileInfo(pdfInvoiceTargetFolder + @"/" + pdfInvoiceFileName);
            if (pdfInvoiceFile.Exists)
                pdfInvoiceFile.Delete();

            // create pdf file
            workbook.SaveToFile(pdfInvoiceFile.FullName, Spire.Xls.FileFormat.PDF);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I suppose you were using Spire.XLS rather than Spire.PDF.
Second, you need to do some page setup before converting. Try below code:

```
 Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[index];
 PageSetup setup = worksheet.PageSetup;
 setup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
 setup.FitToPagesTall = 1;
```